# How to sort the strings by user input

Tags: python-3.x

I am trying to write the program that reads 2 lines from input, first line is alphabet order and second line is string that you want to sort using that order.
e.g
input line 1 -  abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz
input line 2 -  cyxbza
output -  abcxyz

Input line 1 -   zyxwvutsrqponmlkjihgfedcba
Input line 2 - cyxbza
Output -  zyxcba

Can anyone please help?

```
var1= input("Enter Alphabate in Order") 
var2= input("Enter Strings Randomly")

if var1==("zyxwvutsrqponmlkjihgfedcba"): 
    result=var2.sort(reverse=True)   

else:
    result=''.join (sorted(var2))

print(result)
```

Comment: Where does "reversed" come into play? You never mention the reverse order in the problem description.

Comment: Are you simply trying to sort a set of letters alphabetically (forwards or backwards), or are you trying to sort the set of letters based on some arbitrary ordering given by the user?

Comment: @DyZ please check my second example in problem description.. which says... Input line 1 - zyxwvutsrqponmlkjihgfedcba Input line 2 - cyxbza Output - zyxcba. (you can see that when entering the reverse alphabet , it is sorting the  input line 2 in that order and gives the result)

Comment: @JasonWarta "YES" when user enters "abcde" then input line 2 will get sorted in that order but if user enters "zyx.." then input line 2 will get sorted in the reversed order

Comment: Please update your original question. It has to be clear and answerable without the need to read the comments.

Comment: @DyZ I have already given 2 examples as what output I am looking for, kindly check it

Comment: in your examples you're simply sorting alphabetically. this isn't difficult and doesn't require your first input string. However, sorting based on an arbitrary ordering provided by the user is definitely possible, but an entirely different proposition

Comment: Your title contradict your examples. In the title, you say that you want to sort in the _reversed_ order. In the post, you say that the order is in fact defined by the string entered by the user, which may be direct, reversed, or anything else, Make your question and the title consistent.

Comment: @JasonWarta it is based on user input..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can accomplish this by using a sort key that is based on the position (or lack of) of your "to be sorted character" inside the given key:

```
var1 = input("Enter key to sort by - first comes first when sorted") 
var2 = input("Enter Strings Randomly")

# if character in var1 (your key) use that position to sort, else 
# put it to the end (position == lenght of key == after all key-chars)
r = ''.join(sorted(var2, key = lambda x: len(var1) if x not in var1 else var1.find(x)))

print(r)
```

Input:

```
# key:
khbatjm
# data:
abcdefghijklmnoipq
```

Output:

```
khbajmcdefgilnoipq
```

It will sort in order of your key, and any non-contained character is added in its original order to the end of the ordered part.

---

This method is suboptimal, as the position of each character is not cached but search again every time - it would be better/faster to store it as dict - but it is easy to understand. Bonus is: it is able to cope with non-key'ed characters.

Dict-Lookup-Optimization:

```
# inpired by Patrick Haugh answer
posInKey = {ch:pos for pos,ch in enumerate(var1)}  
r = ''.join(sorted(var2, key = lambda x: posInKey.get(x, len(var1))))
```

Comment: thank you for the explanation but first user input will be the same it will be either abcdef or reverse order of alphabet like zyx etc and second input is any random string say "adyoufdh" now if user inputs the reverse alphabet order than var2 will get sorted in the reverse order.

Comment: @KumarKatariya Then you dont need any of this, simply:  `''.join(sorted("someText"))` will sort by alphabet, `''.join(sorted("someText", reverse=True))` will sort by alphabet reversed

Comment: @KumarKatariya also your inputs are just 2 special cases that will be handled correctly - this code could also sort by vowels first, then others: `"aeioubcdfghjklmnpqrstvwxyz"` as key.

Comment: Thanks Patrick will try again, I want to give upvote but do not have enough reputation, I need 15 and I have 14, can you help me up voting the question and will be able to upvote

Answer (score 1):

Here's an example where we have a function that accepts an alphabet and returns a function that sorts strings according to that alphabet, using a [key function](https://docs.python.org/3/howto/sorting.html#key-functions)

```
def encoder(alphabet):
    mapping = {x: i for (i, x) in enumerate(alphabet)}
    def encode(s):
        return ''.join(sorted(s, key=mapping.get))
    return encode

encode = encoder("zyxwvutsrqponmlkjihgfedcba")
encode("cyxbza")
# 'zyxcba'
```

Note that this won't be able to place characters not present in the input to `encoder`.  If you want to add that functionality, you'll have to write a key function that catches the failure of `mapping.get` and returns some other value.

Comment: @PatrickArtner Left as an exercise for the reader :)

Comment: I don't see input function in the code, how users will input their value

Comment: @KumarKatariya You would replace the two strings with calls to `input`.  I provided them so you can paste this into an interpreter and verify its output for your sample input.